# Yan - Drell process

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm looking for more information about Yan - Drell process but didn't manage to find a good place to learn from (still looking for one). I understood that this process can help us to understand the inner structure of hadrons / mesons but I would love to get more information what is going on. In which accelerator this process is actually being researched?

Comment: Unless I am much mistaken the process you are looking for is $q^+ + q^- \to l^+ + l^-$ and is normally called "Drell-Yan". It has been used repeatedly as a physics tool, but I am not aware f any current experiment based on it (doesn't mean much, BTW, I'm not in *that* loop). I was loosely involved with E866 (NuSea) ar Fermilab which used this process as a core physics tool.

Comment: Indeed this is the process. But how this type of collisions can help us to understand internal structure of hadron. What are the benefits over DIS? If possible, I prefer equations / diagrams than just explanation.

Comment: It hs been too long. Every Drell-Yan involves a anti-quark so it is a direct probe of the sea. The reaction has a very clear experimental signature. If you accept iso-spin as a good enough symmetry and use multiple targets you can sort out the *flavor* form-factors much more cleanly than with DIS. The NuSea web site used to have lots of information at varying levels of technical detail. And of course, their papers are a treasure trove.

Comment: Ah...it appears that SeaQuest (E906) is the name of the current generation experiment. See https://www.phy.anl.gov/mep/SeaQuest/ .